# Is There any way to Predict x and y location from one screen size to another?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-screen

i am developing an android app, about joining dots and making picture.
so far i can't find a way to extract exact x and y coordinates of black dots . so I've hard coded x and y locations to draw point on exact black dot of image. It worked wonderful on **1152*720** size ,but problem occurs when i tested it on **480*600** size , **dots misplaced from there exact location** , now

My Question is if I've written something like :

x = 100 ,
y = 200 
(on screen 1152*720)

what will be x and y values in different screen sizes like 480*600 and how to calculate it ? i know it is silly question but i am new to this stuff.

Comment: 1152 -480 = x; so your new location will be x = (x+100)-viewwidth; .. is it good for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question as you have asked it...

```
int oldScreenX // The current x coord
int newScreenX // The new x coord
...
float oldScreenSizeX = 1152.0f;
float newScreenSizeX = 600.0f;
newScreenX = (int)(oldScreenX / oldScreenSizeX) * newScreenSizeX; // Remember to cast the result back to an int
```

Do the same for y.

---

**Additional:**

Perhaps you should reconsider your approach.
The real problem is how do you put the dot in the same location on the **Image**, if the **Image** is being drawn at a different size. So forget about measuring the screen size. Measure the Image size instead.
For example, if you are showing your image in an `ImageView`, you could write a general scaling method like the following:

```
public int scaleCoordinate(int unscaledImageSize, int scaledImageSize, int unscaledCoordinate) {
    scaledCoordinate = (int)(unscaledCoordinate / unscaledImageSize) * scaledImageSize; // Remember to cast the result back to an int
    return scaledCoordinate;
}
```

Then you can use it in your code, something like:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);
Drawable drawable = image.getDrawable();

// Get the original size of the bitmap
int unscaledSizeX = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

// Get the current size it is being drawn at on the screen
int scaledSizeX = imageView.getWidth();

int scaledCoordinateX = scaleCoordinate(unscaledSizeX, scaledSizeX, unscaledCoordinateX);
```

**NOTE:**
The `ImageView` needs to be measured and laid out by the system before calling the above code. If you call it too early `imageView.getWidth()` will return 0.
It would be best to call the above code once the ImageView is actually displayed on the screen (from your `onResume()` or later).

Comment: how can i get oldScreenSizeX , oldScreenSizeY values in android within code?

Answer (score -2):

I  was done this, while studying java may be it will be helpful for you.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;


public class DrawLineOnGivenLocations extends Applet implements          MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{


int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0; 

public void init() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {

    // show status
    showStatus("Moving mouse at " + me.getX() + ", " + me.getY());
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    // save coordinates
    x1 = me.getX();
    y1 = me.getY();
    x2 = me.getX();
    y2 = me.getY();

    repaint();

}
public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.drawLine(x1,y1 ,x2, y2);

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    //repaint();
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}

}
```

Comment: How, exactly, does this answer the OP's question?  The question was about relating x/y positions from screen size to screen size, not being able to click and find coordinates.